# TFS Team Build MSTest run duration too slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, tfsbuild

I run my 700 unit tests in visual studio and they take less than 2 mins.

I also have Team Build set up to do a build and run my unit tests, which takes over 12 mins to run the same tests!

During my exploring of logs etc.. I've found this confusing info:

-If I open the MSTest .trx file (Visual Studio test results file) that was actually generated by Team Build on the server, it says the duration is about 2 mins.

-But when I view the Log from the build explorer, the log entry for unit tests (Run MSTest for Test Assemblies) shows the duration to be about 12 mins.

Anybody got any idea where the extra 10 mins have gone and perhaps more importantly is there something I can turn off to get them back?

TFS 2010, VS 2010.

Thanks,
Mike G

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this includes the publishing time (although it's very unlikely that publishing takes 10 mins). It could if you have a remote TFS server and you upload lots of big assemblies when publishing the test results. If that is indeed the case, I can look further to see if there is an option in the 2010 release that turns off publishing assemblies.

Comment: On a TFS 2015.4 vNext build; the log lists Total Tests 9810, Total Execution time 10.4876 minutes. Then the next few lines are "Publising Test results..." which does take 2-3 minutes also. I'm not sure how noone at MSFT has noticed this.